# Trouble inserting into Azure db from Windows Store app

Tags: c#, azure, windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services

I'm currently working on a Windows Store app (for a school assignment), and I'm having trouble inserting data into my database which is stored in Azure. Whenever I attempt to insert data into the db, the MobileServiceInvalidOperationException gets thrown. My code is as follows:

In my model class

```
class Division
{
    public string Id {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "divisionTitle")]
    public string DivisionTitle {get; set;}
}
```

And the relevant code in my MainPage.xaml.cs file

```
private MobileServiceCollection<Division, Division> divisionItems;
private IMobileServiceTable<Division> divisionTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Division>();

private async void InsertDivision(Division divisionItem)
{
    // This code inserts a new division Item into the database.
    // When the operation completes and Mobile Services has
    // assigned an Id, the item is added to the collection
    try
    {
        await divisionTable.InsertAsync(divisionItem);
        divisionItems.Add(divisionItem);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
    // The MessageDialog that pops up when this exception  //
    // gets thrown is:                                     //
    //                                                     //
    //        Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)             //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
    {
        MessageDialog errormsg = new MessageDialog(e.Message,
            string.Format("{0} (HTTP {1})",
            e.Response.ReasonPhrase,
            (int)e.Response.StatusCode));
        var ignoreAsyncOpResult = errormsg.ShowAsync();
    }
}

private void DivisionButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var DivisionItem = new Division
    {
        DivisionTitle = DivisionInput.Text
    };

    InsertDivision(DivisionItem);
}
```

I also added a script in the management portal:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    if (item.DivisionTitle.length > 15) {
        request.respond(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST, 'Division title must be under 15 characters');
    }
    else {
        request.execute();
    }
}
```

Before making the changes above, I was having no trouble communicating with Azure from within the app and wasn't having any problems inserting data. It's only after editing the script in Azure (the default insert method is simply the `request.execute()` statement), and since I added the InsertDivision method (I was previously entering data into the db directly from the event handler with the command `await App.MobileService.GetTable<Division>().InsertAsync(DivisionItem);`) that this problem has started to occur. I've tried a couple of different things and nothing has worked. After looking at my code does anything stick out? Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the request sent to the service, the property `DivisionTitle` is sent with the first letter in lower case (since you defined it as such with the `JsonProperty` attribute):

```
{"divisionTitle":"the actual title"}
```

On your script, you're trying to access the property `item.DivisionTitle` (which doesn't exist, JavaScript is case-sensitive), and then access a property (`length`) of this undefined value. That will cause an error in your script. If you either change the script to use the actual JSON name (`item.divisionTitle.length > 15`) or change the `JsonProperty` declaration in the client to send the property with the first letter in upper case, it should work.

By the way, if you go to the "logs" tab in the portal, you should see some error which explains why you're getting the internal server error.

Comment: That did the trick! I hate when it's something stupid like that, but the extra set of eyes never hurts. Thanks for helping out.